# Get indeces of columns based on a vector of names (in R)

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe with named columns.

Let's assume:

```r
> colnames(df)
[1] "apple"   "orange"   "banana"   "pear"   "melon"
```

I want to get the indices of the columns that match strings in a vector.

```r
> myNames = c("apple","pear")
> foo(myNames,colnames(df))
[1] 1 4
```

Originally, `which()` and `%in%` came to mind but neither worked in my implementation due to the inputs being both vectors; examples for the sake of completeness:

```r
> which(colnames(df) == myNames )
> myNames %in% colnames(df)
```

Any help on how to do this without a loop would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `match`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`which` and `%in%` are one option

```
x <- c("apple", "orange", "banana", "pear", "melon")
myNames = c("apple","pear")

which(x %in% myNames)
[1] 1 4
```

Another one is `match`

```
match(myNames, x)
[1] 1 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both work. I was using %in% backwards and that was my problem. According to your answer, it should have been `colnames(df) %in% myNames` while I had the opposite.

`match()` is definitely a more compact solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep to find them one by one like this:

```
grep("apple",df)
```

or use this:

```
colno=function(vector,df){
  result=c()
  a=length(vector)

  for(i in 1:a){
    result[i]=grep(vector[i],colnames(df))}
  return(result)}
```

Then call it like,

```
colno(myNames,df)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Fyi, typical is to do `for (i in seq_along(vector))` since length might be zero in which case you have 1:0. Also, you can initialize `result = integer(length(vector))` which is more efficient than dynamically growing it. A free book called the R Inferno has more such R pitfalls if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you for the seq_along advice! I read Inferno but there's only so much I can remember without practicing every single concept.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it